# Springboot / Kotlin: Best Practice to test a Class that injects another @ConfigurationProperties class

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, configurationproperties

I have a project in Kotlin.

I created a `@ConfigurationProperties` class and I would like to know the best practices for unit tests.

The following is my properties class:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
data class MyAppProperties(
    /**
     * Base path to be used by myapp. Default is '/search'.
     */
    val basePath: String = "/myapp"
)
```

I inject MyAppProperties in my Controller:

```
@RestController
final class MyAppController(
    myAppProperties: MyAppProperties
) {

    ...

}
```

I want to test my Controller:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
internal class MyAppControllerTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var myAppProperties: MyAppProperties

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var myAppController: MyAppController

    ...

}
```

But I have the following Mockito error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class com.myapp.MyAppProperties
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
```

What is the best solution to fix this problem:

- Allow Mockito to mock final class: https://blog.mindorks.com/mockito-cannot-mock-in-kotlin

```
    /src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker: mock-maker-inline
```

This solution seems good since we don't modify the existing code but it adds a behavior to Mockito for the whole project and all final classes.

- Make my properties class `open`

```
    open class MyAppProperties...
```

This solution requires modifying the code and makes the class extensible, which may not be a good thing?

- Make all @ConfigurationProperties classes open via the Maven configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                <arg>-Xjvm-default=enable</arg>
            </args>
            <compilerPlugins>
                <plugin>all-open</plugin>
            </compilerPlugins>
            <pluginOptions>
                <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties</option>
            </pluginOptions>
        </configuration>
        ...
    </plugin>
```

This solution does not require modifying the code but make all @ConfigurationProperties classes `open`, which may not be a good thing?

- Do not mock the properties class and initialize it in MyAppControllerTest:

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
    internal class MyAppControllerTest {
    
        val myAppProperties: MyAppProperties = MyAppProperties("/mypath")
    
        ...
    }
```

This does not allow us to give a specific behaviour according to the test.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for a pure unit test, I would recommend going with your last approach (initialization). It's perfectly normal to initialize a test subject differently in different tests which in your case means inserting different configurations. You can unify them using `@Nested` if you want to. Mocking a data class looks too much as you're effectively mocking a getter. You wouldn't mock a plain entity returned by a repository either. Your code won't be any longer (probably shorter) and (although not notable as we're talking microseconds) a bit faster.

Another consideration: with a controller basically being a plain pass-through to a service layer, they are often only covered in integration tests to Tests. For your specific test this would require to pass in a different configuration. This would impact your overall test speed though as for a new configuration, a new spring context has to be initialized.